# App Store Rank After App Update

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

For example my App is #100 on top free apps in one country. Will it be reseted after app update? I want to ask Apple to do 1 day expedited review.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about App Store policies and practices, not programming.

Comment: It's about algorithm. App Store algorithm.

Comment: Which is not an algorithm that you developed, or which you are working on. Stack Overflow is a community for questions about computer programming, not just about computers in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rankings seem to be built based on the number of downloads the app gets. So an update won't change anything.

Expedited reviews are for urgent cases (i.e. non-functioning app in store etc.).

Comment: I know it. There is critical bug in app.